# How to resolve error 'NotNullWhen attribute is inaccessible due to its protection level'

Tags: c#, nullability

I have the following extension method and I'm trying to decorate the `out` parameter (`T value`) with the `NotNullWhen` attribute. However, it displays the error *'NotNullWhen attribute is inaccessible due to its protection level'* that I can't figure out why?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

    internal static class Extensions
    {
        public static bool TryGetValueForAssignableType<T>(this IDictionary<Type, T> dictionary, Type key, [NotNullWhen(true)] out T value)
        {
            value = default;

            foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            {
                if (pair.Key.IsAssignableFrom(key))
                {
                    value = pair.Value;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

I've tried changing the class access modifier to `public` with no effect. I also have C# 8 `nullable` context enabled for the class library.

Any idea how to resolve this?

**Edit:**

I just tried creating a new class library with just the extensions class above. Now it displays 'The type of namespace name 'NotNullWhen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)'. I've already included `using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;` which is greyed out though.
 The project file contains the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Everything compiles for me. Can you add some more information? Does the library itself fails to compile?

Comment: The library compiles when I remove the attribute. Just added some more details to the question.

Comment: @GuruStron did you have to install any nuget packages separately? Do you have the `nullable` context enabled for the project (not sure if this makes a difference though)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your open [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullwhenattribute?view=netstandard-2.1) you will see that `NotNullWhenAttribute` applies to:

- .NET Core 3.0, Core 3.1, 5, 6, 7, 8
- .NET Standard 2.1

TBH I failed to build lib against `.NET Standard 2.1` also, but you try can either install nuget like [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nullable) or implement this attribute yourself ([like it is done in the runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Diagnostics/CodeAnalysis/NullableAttributes.cs#L69)), cause AFAIK compiler quite often relies on naming and/or duck typing.

Comment: I didn't realise it had to be `netstardard2.1`. I added a custom one with the same name and it works fine now. Thanks